# Why am I getting this error ? I just want to plot my equations in Octave

Tags: octave

```
%z = ratio of damping co-efficients , z<1
%wn = natural frequency in rad/sec
%wd = frequency of damped osciallations
%x_0 = amp
%phi = initial phase
%t = time
%%
z = 0.6943;
wn = 50;
wd = sqrt(1-(z^2))*wn;
x_0 = 42;
phi = pi/12;
t = linspace(0,100,1000);
x = x_0.*exp(-z*wn*t).*sin(phi+(wd*t));
plot(t,x);

error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1000, op2 is 1x1000)
error: called from
    /home/koustubhjain/Documents/Damped_Oscialltion_(z<1).m at line 14 column 3
```

I am completely new to Octave/MATLAB, I just want to plot my equations and get a graph for them. Did I do something wrong with the multiplication ? Please someone help

Also the curve I am trying to plot should look something like a sinusoidal with decreasing amplitude, that's what my teacher told. But If I replace the multiplication signs with .*, all I get is a sort of a straight line.

Comment: please, put your code and errors as text, not as images. You probably want the operator `.*` instead of `*`

Comment: Changing the operator to `.*` fixes the error, so now the question about the curve is a completely different question than the original (and the headline).

Comment: @nielsen know why that might be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The curve tends to 0 and the range of `t` is so wide to see something. Try to plot for `t` from 0 to 0.5 (instead of from 0 to 100) and you will see your curve.